# Excelからグラフをpng形式で出力したい

Tags: python, python3, excel

#### 実現したいこと

クロス集計表とグラフを含むExcelファイルから、グラフをpng形式で抜き出したいです。
※グラフは１シートに対して複数あるので個別に抜き出しを行いたい。

#### 課題

・openpyxlでは１シートに複数のグラフがある場合、グラフのオブジェクト名を指定して取り込む必要がありそうだが、方法が見つけられていおりません。（ドキュメント見る限りなさそう）

・xlwingsではExcelを開いてでしか実行できない、かつグラフ図を取り込む場合と取り込まない場合があり、その原因の特定ができておりません。

#### 具体的な質問

・openpyxlライブラリで複数のグラフを指定して、PDF変換（poppler使用）→png形式で保存は可能でしょうか？
・xlwingsではpng形式で保存できることは確認したが、できる場合できない場合が発生するので、回避方法はありますでしょうか？
・上記以外に実現可能なexcel操作のライブラリはありますでしょうか？

Comment: 参考: [How can I save an excel chart as an image using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61657717/2322778)

Comment: こんな記事 [【よく分かる】xlwingsでExcelを制御しよう...](https://resanaplaza.com/2021/08/29/%E3%80%90%E3%82%88%E3%81%8F%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%80%91xlwings%E3%81%A7excel%E3%82%92%E5%88%B6%E5%BE%A1%E3%81%97%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-by-python/), [【よく分かる】xlwings でExcelマクロ...](https://resanaplaza.com/2021/08/29/%e3%80%90%e3%82%88%e3%81%8f%e5%88%86%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8b%e3%80%91xlwings-%e3%81%a7excel%e3%83%9e%e3%82%af%e3%83%ad%e3%82%92%e5%ae%9f%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%97%e3%82%88%e3%81%86-by-python/), [PythonでExcelマクロ実行！...](https://fastclassinfo.com/entry/run_excelvba_from_python/) があって、VBAマクロの実行が必要なのでは？ その場合OpenPyXLは使えないでしょう。